# url after spring maven deployment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, url

I have a basic question about deployment but I can't seem to find an answer on google...

I am working on a jakarta project and it's the first time I do the deployment.
Since I am using Spring-boot maven, I know there is an embedded tomcat that will launch with the jar.
My issue is, I don't know what url to use to check my project is working...

Before, I used the address `http://localhost:9091/contextPath/endpoint`, but now, I only get a whiteScreen...

So my question is, what url should I use ? Also, is there something else to do after packaging ?
Thank you for your answers.

EDIT: 
Alright, so I tried actuator but that didn't help me...
With `/actuator/mappings`, I could see that my endpoints are correctly configured but when I use the executable jar, `http://localhost:9091/contextPath/endpoint` odes not work while it does if I compile with my IDE...
I don't know what url to connect to just to see the index... I'm using a very basic spring framework (boot and mvc) and my IDE is intellij community if this helps anyone

EDIT 2:
I tried to deploy the app on a local Tomcat9 to see if something would change but the connexion is reinitialized everytime I try to deploy a war using the manager, and there was no trace of error in the logs.
I tried using ./mvnw and it did work, endpoint and all, but it implies working with IDE environment
I tried using java (openjdk 13) and it compiled, but i couldn"t acces my own endpoint. I could still access the actuator endpoints so i don't know what to make of it.

Should the url be different depending on whether we are using IDE environment or just the jar?

EDIT 3: 
Ok, I think have a lead but I have no idea how to resolve this:
when I began the web part of the application, I created a `WEB-INF` folder where I put all my jsp. My js and css files were in the `resources/static` folder. I tried once to put the jsp in the resources folder but it didn't work so I didn't push too hard.
Now, when I unzip the jar, i find my css and js files, but not my jsp.
When I unzip my war file, I have everything, but when I try to deploy it on a separate tomcat server, the connexion resets and I don't know why because nothing is written in the logs.

The issue then becomes:

Right now, I have

```
└──src
   └──main
      ├──java
      ├──resources
      |  ├──static
      |  |  ├──css
      |  |  └──js
      |  └──template
      └──webapp
         └──WEB-INF
            └──classes
               └──jsp
```

What is the standard tree in intellij with jsp ?

Comment: Are you deploying to a server or using the embedded server. You are mentioning deploying, which would mean you aren't using your embedded server (which you then only use for local development).

Comment: I am producing a jar and then launching which if I understand it rigth should mean it's the embedded server I'm using.

Comment: How are you launching the jar? In cli? E.g. `java -jar target/name-of-the-jar.jar` or maven(wrapper?) `./mvnw spring-boot:run`? Is there anything in the logs? Or does it at least start successfully (e.g. you see `Started xyz in x.xxx seconds (JVM running for x.xxx)`)?

Comment: To be honest, I just doubleclicked on the jar. I know at least the server launched and maybe some of the application because actuator was working.
I tried both java and maven with the commands you showed, and while maven worked, java put me an error : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/mytree/Application has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to make it work.
I'm going to describe here everything of note that I encountered.
First, when I called my app to the usual url, there was no response (whiteLabel).
I added test logs and i found that I indeed called m controller.
I unzipped the jar and war i produced and came to the conclusion that the issue was architectural. I couldn't use jar, I had to use the war file.
I tried to deploy on a local tomcat server using the manager, but it always resetted the connection, so I took the manual approach - copy pasting the war file in the webapp directory.
Finally, the web pages were accessible in the browser.
Thank you for all the tips given during my research!

Answer (score 0):

By default Spring Boot apps are on port 8080.
Can you try `http://localhost:8080`?

Port can be changed in `application.properties` (or `application.yml`, `application-profile.properties` etc.) via `server.port` property (e.g. `server.port=8888`).

Comment: I did change the server port, I added the following line to my application.properties file : `server.port=9091`. I know it's listening because it's not the same screen as when I'm on another, non-listening port

Comment: So you're trying to find some url that "returns something" out of the box? Then try some of [actuator endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-enabling). By default only [some](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints) of them are accessible. Or do you have some custom controller?

Comment: I use spring, so i just have classes annoted `@Controller` with methods annoted `@GetMapping("/url")`

Answer (score 0):

```
`http://endpoint:{PORT}/actuator/health`  or `http://endpoint:{PORT}/actuator/status`
```

it should help but it must require spring-boot-actuator as a dependency in your pom/gradle file.

Comment: I tried your url but it didn't work at all... I think you meant something like `http://localhost:{PORT}/actuator/status` ? But also, I didn't find an actuator endpoint named "status"... and `info` sends back an empty json

Comment: Try health instade of status